What is the logic behind the new reality in the fourth season of The Umbrella Academy?
In the third season of The Umbrella Academy, we conclude with two remaining members of the Sparrow Academy: Sloane and Ben.
While the Sparrow version of Ben continues into the next chapter, Sloane is simply gone.
Meanwhile, Ray—Allison's husband—appears as Claire's father despite originally belonging to a different timeline (i.e., the Kennedy timeline).
How is this possible?
Is there any hint from the authors? Did I miss something? Is it mentioned in the comic book the series is based on?"

Where is it written that is must be self-consistent? It's story-telling, not formal logic.

Sorry? Why would you even expect that the words "logic" and "Umbrella Academy" should ever be used together?

How on earth is this opinion based?

What sort of answer could we possibly give? It's the unification of the "shadow selves" (in Jungian terms they were the same people, Umbrella and Sparrow) - that's what the writers had in mind, or some other existentialist reason perhaps? @fez Seems O/B to me unless you've a different idea.

@JiminyCricket. - just because you don’t know what answer to give doesn’t mean this is opinion based. “We don’t know” is a perfectly valid answer. Are you 100% sure there’s no out of universe answer given by any of the writers or producers? There’s nothing in the question that is soliciting an opinion and closing just because you don’t know how to answer a question is wrong

I agree. I guess I'm too into it to be objective about the possibility of an "objective" answer to this. I'll step back. (Just to note, I wasn't one of the close-voters) @fez

One thing, could TGar state if they want an in-universe answer or a "the screenwriters said" sort of answer.

Having the caveat "is this answered in or out of universe in any way" does sound better, but I don't believe questions need to specify this. If the only answers that can possibly be drawn are either wild speculation or "we don't know" that still doesn't mean the question itself is opinion based

(Bit of a meta conversation happening) If you think that's OK, I'll defer to your judgment, It's too late at night for me to think of a good reason to disagree :) @fez

@JiminyCricket. don’t think it’s opinion-based (why would it be?), and I don’t want to add "the screenwriters said", even though that would certainly be a valid answer. I’d also appreciate an 'in-universe' explanation—maybe I missed something in the series, or perhaps it was covered in the original comic book (I really don't know)."

I added some questions at the end.

I don't think it is ever spelled out, but the reset in the hotel is intended to shape the universe at the whim of the operator. That's clear from it's introduction. The consequences of the reshaping show that Hargreaves gets the reset he wants, but also that Alison was able to assert some influence as well. The exact details don't conform to logic as far as I can tell. The whole of season 4 is then demonstrating that just because you can shape reality to your will doesn't mean you actually know or get that you want.

Looking at the wiki entries, hotel oblivion appears to be a super-person prison in the comics. A different and unrelated concept.

@Jontia sounds very reasonable. Will you consider answering on this base?

I haven't personally read the comics, but from the Polygon Article and the Wiki Stub in the Comics Hotel Oblivion is a prison for super-powered people instead of the reality resetting and rebuilding concept introduced in the Netflix series. So combining the two mediums is not going to help here.

The comics’ Hotel Oblivion isn’t a hotel at all. It’s a prison for the most infamous villains that the Umbrella Academy has ever defeated. It’s a twisted place where every sentence is a life sentence, a single cockroach serves as dinner, and prisoners are often driven mad. Since Hargreeves built Hotel Oblivion on a distant planet in a pocket dimension, it’s (nearly) impossible for the inmates to escape.

In the Netflix show the Hotel Oblivion is built around a portal to another dimension that contains a machine capable of resetting the universe. It's difficult to see where this is spelled out during the build up throughout season 3, as it wasn't a surprise reveal in episode 10, but it's only in the final episode that I found direct dialogue confirming it.

Somewhere in this hotel is the key to resetting the universe. We just need to find the sigil!

Alison's involvement with Hargreaves' plan is seen in S03E09 from Five's drunken perspective and so we never get any clarity on the details. But again in S03E10, the fact of the deal is raised

Alison: You know, I heard that you blacked out last night.
Five: I did, and it took me a while to remember what I saw, but I do remember, Allison. You and Dad made some kind of deal.

So in essence we know the plan is to reset the universe to some other state. Hargreaves has clearly at least suggested to Alison that the end state is under their control in some way, otherwise he has nothing to bargain with to bring Alison on side. Added to this is the way he holds her back from taking a place on a sigil to activate the machine.
The overall implication is that the user of the machine is able to reset the whole of reality according to their will, with no reference to logic or causality by simply creating the end state desired by the user. The finale of the episode bears this out as we see from the question. Logical inconsistencies such as Ray out of time, Claire returned but apparently having a different father and Hargreaves' wife restored to him, his financial empire raised to entirely new levels, Luther's revival and Sloane's disappearance are simply ignored.
And then, the whole of season 4 is then demonstrating that just because you can shape reality to your will doesn't mean you actually know or get that you want.

Great answer! I just want to point out that drunk number Five is seeing the deal between Reginald and Allison, not Victor. Maybe there is a difference between the script and the show (I don't know).

@T'gar I will update. And then at some point watch the episodes again, because there is so much Alison and Victor drama that I'm sure there is something in there too.
